# Pandas counts in a table as frequency based on a groupby sum

Tags: python, pandas

If someone can help me out with this. I have two different group by statements.

```
df_base.groupby( ['cdr3_len','Isotype'], as_index=False).sum()

     cdr3_len Isotype    count
0           0     IgG    12148
1           0     IgM    40918
2           1     IgG     4723
3           1     IgM    11107
4           2     IgG     5633
5           2     IgM    17684
6           3     IgG    10332
7           3     IgM    21621
8           4     IgG     9301
9           4     IgM    26348
10          5     IgG   472232
11          5     IgM   351317
12          6     IgG    81520
13          6     IgM   480543
14          7     IgG   263317
15          7     IgM   657392
```

I want the counts to appear as frequency based on a different groupby statement.

```
df_new = df_base.groupby('Isotype',as_index=False).sum()[['Isotype','count']]
IgG    20315380
IgM    70268132
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

So I want a new columns called frequency that takes the count divided by the groupby of just the isotype.

So something like

```
df_base['Frequency'] = df_base['count]/df_new[df_new['isotype'] == df_base['isotype']['count']
```

But obviously this does not work since series lengths are not the same. Any ideas

Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try merging the groupby DF's on the Isotype column, and then do something in the format of new_column = column_A/column_B

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for transform:

```
df_new = df_base.groupby( ['cdr3_len','Isotype'], as_index=False).sum()

# This creates an array of the same length as the original dataset.
df_new['subtotal'] = df_new.groupby('Isotype')['count'].transform(sum)

df_new['freq'] = df_new['count'] / df_new['subtotal']
```